# Write/Read .ini (configuration file) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a configuration file as below:

```
    [config1]
    V1 = 1
    V2 = 2
    V2 = 3

    [config2]
    V1 = 4
    V2 = 5
    V3 = 6
```

I want to change the V3 on each config if the V1 is 1.

Is there a way to do this using excel VBA? This file is saved as txt file.

Comment: You can search for `VB6` and `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString` Win32 API functions

Comment: Does your text file look like the above, or is it comma separated ? Do you want to open and _see_ the file before making changes ?

Comment: **Is there a way to do this using excel VBA?** I would write `Yes` and make that an answer, but it would not be very fair to anyone. If you read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to show your efforts and where they fail, you'll get much more helpful response from the community.

Comment: dear all, thanks a lot for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a search and replace routine from Steve Rindsberg that should get you started. You'll have to insert an **If THEN** statement (or something like that) to replace according to your criteria. I'm not familiar with editing text files, but thought this might help.

```
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

' Edit as needed
sFileName = "C:\Temp\test.txt"

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "THIS", "THAT")

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Mitch thank you for your advice that i can start the way.